# Stubborn rear fog light (BMW E46)

Tags: electrical, bmw, lights

The rear fog light in my BMW E46 2001 is broken.

Obviously, I first tried replacing the bulb itself, but the old bulb was still fine. I tried with a new bulb anyway, but the light didn't work.

I visually checked the wiring in the trunk and especially the connection from the trunk to the car, and everything seemed fine. The housing unit is completely clean, by the way.

When I turn on the light in the car, the dash indicator does come, but the light itself does not. I'm not sure where to look anymore, since the bulb and the wiring seem to be the two major culprits.

I looked on the internet for answers, but I always come across the same answer: check the wiring. Which I already did. At least visually.

Is there anything else I should check? Any particular fuses (I looked on the diagram and I can't find any fuses specifically related to the rear fog light), or other weak spots in the wiring? Any other suggestions are obviously welcome as well.

Comment: Are you talking about the tail light? Fog lights (at least in America) are the two lights on the front of the car near the bottom that turn on with the button next to the headlight switch. On the BMW, a green light on the dash will turn on when the fog lights are on.

Comment: There are two fog lights on the front of the car and one fog light in the rear (only on the left side; although some cars have two rear fog lights) too. This is required for all cars in Europe; in the US, it's indeed not required, though common there on the European brands as well.

Comment: Interesting. I know on the American E46 there was a grounding issue in the tail lights. The wiring would not be obviously bad, but the connector would corrode from the heat because it wasn't making a large enough connection. The fix was to add a wire from the ground wire directly to the plate which grounds all the lights. You might want to look into that - I had to do it on mine.

Comment: Have you checked the contacts of the bulb socket to ensure they are free of different type of corrosion like rust?